# Django でFormViewを使って入力→確認画面の流れを作っているのですが。。。

Tags: django

Django初心者ですが、仕事上在庫管理のシステムを組んでいます。

タイトルにもある通り、入力→確認画面→登録の順で組もうと考えています。

入力Formまでは組み終わったのですが、確認画面で嵌ってしまいました。

modelsでForeignKeyにてリレーションを行なっていますが、HTMLテンプレートに表示する際にリレー先のidしか表示できません。

・models.py

```
class Storage_loca_996(models.Model):
　 Company_Name = models.CharField( "社名" ,max_length=255) 

   def __str__(self):
       return self.Company_Name


class wh_control_997(models.Model):
   Stock = models.IntegerField("在庫")
   Storage_Location = models.ForeignKey(
      'Storage_loca_996',
      on_delete=models.PROTECT,
      related_name='Storage_Location',
      verbose_name='保管場所',
      blank=True ,
      null=True ,
      )
```

・forms.py

```
class StockInfo(forms.ModelForm):

   class Meta:
      model = wh_control_997
      fields = "__all__"

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      for field in self.fields.values():
         field.widget.attrs["class"] = "form-control"
```

・views.py

```
class StockDataConfirm(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.FormView):
   form_class = StockInfo

   def form_valid(self, form):
      return render(self.request, 'growth/stock/confirm.html', {'form': form})

  def form_invalid(self, form):
      return render(self.request, 'growth/stock/create.html', {'form': form}}
```

・HTML create.html

```
    <form action="{% url 'growth:stock_confirm' %}" method="POST">
  <td style="vertical-align: middle;width:200px;"><label for="{{ form.Stock.id_for_label.as_hidden }}">{{ form.Stock.label_ta.as_hiddeng }}</label></td>
  <input type="hidden" name="Stock" id="id_Stock" value=1>


 <table class="table">
   {{ form.non_field_errors }}

         <tr class="warning">
             <td style="vertical-align: middle;width:200px;"><label for="{{ form.Storage_Location.id_for_label }}">{{ form.Storage_Location.label_tag }}</label></td>
             <td>{{ form.Storage_Location }}{{ form.Storage_Location.errors }}

             </td>
   </table>

 {% csrf_token %}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg btn-block"> 登　　　録</button>
</form>
```

・HTML confirm.html

```
{{ form.Stock.as_hidden }}
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    {% for field in form %}
     <tr>
      <td style='text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;width:250px;'><p for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label_tag }}</p></td>
      <td style='text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;'><p>{{ field.value }}</p></td>
    </tr>

    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
<form action="{% url 'stock_create' %}" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg btn-block">戻   る</button>
    {% for field in form %}{{ field.as_hidden }}{% endfor %}
    {% csrf_token %}
</form>
<br>
<form action="{% url 'stock_data_create' %}" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg btn-block">登　　　録</button>
    {% for field in form %}{{ field.as_hidden }}{% endfor %}
    {% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

こんな感じで組んで見たのですが、入力画面はCompany_Nameで表示されるのですが、入力後の確認画面で、idになってしまいます。

1日中色々と試して見たのですが、なかなかできずモヤモヤしていたので、質問させていただきました。
お忙しいところ大変もうしわけございませんが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `confirm.html`と`create.html`の2つあるんですよね？であれば、質問を編集して、両者を載せてください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
編集します＾＾

Comment: `confirm.htm`（`{{ field }}`）と`create.html`（`{{ form.Storage_Location }}`）で書き方が違うので、後者に統一すればいいような気がしますが、それではダメなんですかね？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
間違いがあったので、修正いたしました。
confirm　{{ field }}　→　{{ field.value }}
でした。お詫びいたします。

{% for field in form %}で同じように出力させて見ましたが、{{ field.value }}は、idの表示となってしまいます。

また、confirm.htmlで　{{ form.Storage_Location }}　を表示させると、TEXTエリアに結果が入った状態で表示されます。
登録内容を確認するページなので、結果だけを表示させたかったのですが、なかなか難しいものですね＾＾；

Comment: `{{ form.Storage_Location }}`が、`confirm.html`では想定通り表示されて、`create.html`では想定通り表示されないということですか？問題とは関係ないないと思いますが、`form.Stock.label_ta.as_hiddeng`のtypoがあります。→`form.Stock.label_tag.as_hidden`ですかね。

Comment: お忙しい中ありがとうございます。
想定通りに表示されないのです。

後者は、「form.Stock.label_tag.as_hidden」でお間違いないです。

Comment: 解決しました！Kohei TAMURA様ありがとうございました。

Comment: そうですか。サンプルアプリでもつくってみないと原因分からないかなぁと思っていたので、よかったです。時間があるときに何が原因だったかを回答に書いておいてください。